# JavaScript Keyword Checker

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyword

I have a script that checks a bulk of text against an array of keywords and then returns the count. What I now need it to be able to do is filter out keywords that may contain another keyword already. For example:

> apples are delicious, especially red apples.

The count currently looks like this:

```
apples - 2 (counts "apples" twice)
red apples - 1
```

What I want to happen is for the keywords to be stand alone, like this:

```
apples - 1
red apples - 1
```

My basic script to check keywords:

```
content = ed.getContent().toLowerCase();
var words = ["apples", "red apples"];       
var count = [];                         

for (var i = 0, len = words.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (text.indexOf(words[i].toLowerCase()) > -1){
        var regex = new RegExp(words[i], "g");
        count[i] = (content.match(regex) || []).length;
        console.log(words[i] + " " + count[i]);
    }
}
```

I'm stuck! Any help or nudges in the right direction is always much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are many ways to do this. I think the simplest is to sort the words and trim the content.

https://jsfiddle.net/a0h7xbfu/8/

```
var content = "red apples apples";
var words = ["apples", "red apples"];
var count = [];

words.sort(function(a, b) {
  var lenA = a.length;
  var lenB = b.length;
  if (lenA === lenB) {
    return 0;
  }
  return (lenA > lenB) ? -1 : 1;
});

words.forEach(function(word) {
  var regex = new RegExp(word, "g");
  var match = content.match(regex);
  if (match) {
    console.log(word + ": " + match.length);
    content = content.replace(regex, '');
  }
});
```

Comment: This is really helpful thank you. I was having a hard time getting my head around the idea but seeing how you've done it by first sorting in string length order makes perfect sense. Thank you!